# Is it necessary to use baked texture in cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, texture-baking

I have heard that, if we bake the textures then then it will define more quality and it makes more faster in rendering in cycles...

Comment: Rendering in cycles, is essentially the act of calculating the lighting and it's effect on the scene. Baking is a form of "pre-calculating" you can do for objects, that makes the textures "remember" the effects of the render. Once this is done, time is saved in the final render, because there is no need to re-calculate the lighting on the baked objects. This can even make viewing in real-time possible. This is a very rudimentary description, however - a much better breakdown can be found here - https://www.blenderguru.com/tutorials/introduction-baking-cycles

Comment: It is positively **not** necessary.